# R - Replacing Specific Columns' Data

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe

I'm connecting to my Vertica Database and retrieve huge amount of data. There are NAs in the dataset in all columns. But I want to find NAs from specific columns' and replace with 0.

How should I do that ?

Thanks !

Comment: `df[specificColumns][is.na(df[specificColumns])] <- 0`? (Replace "specificColumns" with a vector of the columns in which you need to replace NA with 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on my comment and make it into an answer, here's a minimal reproducible example:

```
set.seed(1)
mydf <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(c(1:2, NA), 50, replace = TRUE), ncol = 10))
mydf
#   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10
# 1  1 NA  1  2 NA  2  2 NA NA  NA
# 2  2 NA  1 NA  1  1  2 NA  2   1
# 3  2  2 NA NA  2  2  2  1 NA   2
# 4 NA  2  2  2  1 NA  1 NA  2  NA
# 5  1  1 NA NA  1  2 NA  2  2  NA
```

Now, if we wanted to replace `NA` with "0", but only in columns 1, 3, 7, and 8, you can use:

```
mydf[c(1, 3, 7, 8)][is.na(mydf[c(1, 3, 7, 8)])] <- 0
mydf
#   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10
# 1  1 NA  1  2 NA  2  2  0 NA  NA
# 2  2 NA  1 NA  1  1  2  0  2   1
# 3  2  2  0 NA  2  2  2  1 NA   2
# 4  0  2  2  2  1 NA  1  0  2  NA
# 5  1  1  0 NA  1  2  0  2  2  NA
```

---

Instead of column numeric index positions, you can use a vector of column names (which will be safer than the numeric positions). Additionally, your code might be easier if the vector of column names or index positions you're working on were stored in a separate vector. Both of those concepts are demonstrated below, where we replace `NA` values in variables "V2", "V4" and "V5" with "-999".

```
changeMe <- c("V2", "V4", "V5")
mydf[changeMe][is.na(mydf[changeMe])] <- -999
mydf
#   V1   V2 V3   V4   V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10
# 1  1 -999  1    2 -999  2  2  0 NA  NA
# 2  2 -999  1 -999    1  1  2  0  2   1
# 3  2    2  0 -999    2  2  2  1 NA   2
# 4  0    2  2    2    1 NA  1  0  2  NA
# 5  1    1  0 -999    1  2  0  2  2  NA
```